# Related Posts logic on Yii2 blog

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a custom CMS built on Yii2 and I need "related posts" functionality. The problem is I don't fully understand how to build an "appropriate" MySQL query. The way I see it:

1. we have Post X with tag A, tag B, tag C...
2. we cross-reference all the Posts under tags A, B, C...
3. we obtained N posts and we need to sort them from the most referenced to the least referenced
4. profit

But I don't know how to put all this into MySQL. everything I google'd is not working.

any help will be appreciated.

**UPD2**. Unfortunately, the suggestion by @Joe Miller won't work.
**UPD**. *tables structure*

post

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title           | varchar(160) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| slug            | varchar(160) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content         | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cover_image_url | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| author_id       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status          | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| access_type     | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

post_tags

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| post_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tag_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

tags

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| slug        | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: show me the table schema please

Comment: updated the original post. thanks

Comment: What do you mean for most referenced ?

Comment: I mean "posts that have most tags in common with Post X"